# Can't get the http response using telnet from the command line

Tags: windows-7, command-line, cmd, telnet

I'm using Windows 7 (x64). I want to send an http request from a command line and to get a response. I use Telnet. I type in the command line: `telnet www.google.com 80`. 
[image]
After I press "enter" the screen becomes black (everything disappears from the cmd screen).
[image]

After a couple of minutes it shows a standard command prompt without outputting anything.
[image]

When I launch telnet in my command line (typing `telnet` without parameters) and type `o www.google.com 80`, it outputs `Connecting to www.google.com`. After a few minutes it says `press any key`. After pressing any key it outputs `The connection was lost`

My question is: how can I actually get an http response? What am doing wrong?

Comment: A webserver will expect a `GET` or `POST` request within a very short time-out. You may not be able to type quickly enough for a given server.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The connection is established and waiting for you to enter a command. Type `GET / HTTP/1.0` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> twice. The command is case-sensitive. It's not displayed as you type, because localecho is off by default. You can enable localecho like this:

```
C:\>telnet
Welcome to Microsoft Telnet Client

Escape Character is 'CTRL++'

Microsoft Telnet> set localecho
Local echo on
Microsoft Telnet> open www.example.com 80
Connecting To www.example.com...
GET / HTTP/1.0
```

Or you could use [`PuTTY`](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/%7Esgtatham/putty/), which displays the typed text by default (you need to configure the session to not close the Window on exit, though).

For more information about HTTP see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol). For the protocol specification see [RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616).

Comment: The only issue is that when I type any letters, it doesn't output them... But I typed as you said and it worked (I got the response)!
Do you know what is the problem with outputting symbols which I type?